# Is there an easyway to increment a date by a regular increment?

Tags: php, datetime

I have datestamps in the format `YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`
Is there an easy way to increase or decrease this by a set amount (say 1 hour or 1 day)?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+date+php

Comment: @Gordon: looks like date/time math needs it own faq. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$plus_day = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strotime($your_time . " + 1 day"));
$plus_hour = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strotime($your_time . " + 1 hour"));
```

Comment: you're on fire today! Every question I've looked at all day, it's you with the answers!

Comment: Close, but that returns it as seconds timestamp, not formated... Should be more like `$plusday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($your_time . " + 1 day"));`

Comment: @aslum: yes, exactly. Added for you

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to work with the `DateTime` class, which has a variety of ways of manipulating the date/time.

```
$incremented = date_create($date)->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Same as above
// $incremented = date_create($date . ' +1 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// $incremented = date_create($date)->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// $date = new DateTime($date); $date->modify('+1 day'); $incremented = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: +1. I find the DateTime family to be more flexible and self documenting than the traditional date/time functions -- especially with regards to timezone and daylight savings. Not to mention you get all the benefits of OOP.

Answer (score 2):

See MySQL [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) FROM tablename
```

**Update**
See @genesis' answer for the PHP way. Which you choose is up to whether you want to do the interval in mysql or php (I suspect PHP is the best option)